# Подключить GLFW к CLion

Tags: c++, clion

Доброго времени суток! Я хочу подключить GLFW библиотеку к CLion. Раньше я работал в Visual Studio (там довольно просто с установкой), но теперь решил перейти на CLion и не знаю как подключить туда GLFW..

Comment: Поместил dll-ки, lib'ы и include (содержимое) в соответствующие папки в MinGW . Теперь видит glfw, автодополнение работает, но при компиляции вылетает что undefined и так дальше...

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй установить FreeGlut

```
$ sudo apt-get install freeglut freeglut-dev
$ g++ main.cpp -lGL -lglut
```

Comment: Вот только в вопросе речь шла о Windows.